# A colon before a number in numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, raspberry-pi

I'm using a camera to store raw data in a numpy array, but I don't know What does mean a colon before a number in numpy array?

```
import numpy as np
import picamera

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (128, 112)
data = np.empty((128, 112, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
camera.capture(data, 'rgb')
data = data[:128, :112]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[numpy array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) is explained in the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

this example shows what is selected:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(64).reshape(8, 8)
print(data)
data = data[:3, :5]
print(data)
```

the result will be the first 5 elements of the first 3 rows of the array.

as in standard python `lst[:3]` means everything up to the third element (i.e. the element with index `< 3`). in numpy you can do the same for every dimension with the syntax given in your question.