# Function of colon in Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to understand this line of Python.

```
 dP = -(dt / tau_stdp) * P[:, it] + A_plus * pre_spike_train_ex[:, it + 1]
```

but I can't find what the  ' : ' does in these NumPy arrays

Comment: It's for slicing a range of elements, similar to slicing a list or string.

Comment: Slicing NumPy arrays is the same as slicing in lists. I would recommend checking this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works

In essence, in your code, `P[:, it]` means you are looking at the elements from all the rows and only the `it`th column of `P`.

Comment: Inside `[]` a `:` is a python `slice`.  The fuller usage is `start:stop:step`, which you should have learned in Python basics.  Here it 'selects' all of one dimension of a 2d array.  I suggest spending some time on numpy fundamentals, especially indexing, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A colon before a number in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44337881/a-colon-before-a-number-in-numpy-array)